# How do I expose the visible property of an image inside a user control (c#)?

Tags: c#, user-controls

Problem:

A control that shows each user which quizzes they have passed out of a possible four.

My solution:

Create user control that lists the name of the quizzes and has a checkmark at the end of each quiz name that I would like to make visible when they pass a quiz.

The actual user control is inside of my master page.

From reading other posts, I understand that I need to make the image.visible property public in the control code behind. I have tried this several ways and haven't had much luck.

So how do I expose the .visible property of an image inside of my user control?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:

```
public Boolean ImageIsVisible
{
    set { this.yourImage.Visible = value; }
    get { return this.yourImage.Visible; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hree ways I can think of...

In the USER control, just set the image as public instead of default - private, but that exposes ALL the elements.

Another is to create a property at the user control level that passes on to the ex:

```
public Boolean ImgVisible
{
  get { return this.YourImageControl.Visible; }
  set { this.YourImageControl.Visible = value; }
}
```

Or, just create as a function in your user control...

```
public void ImgVisible( Boolean ShowIt )
{
  this.YourImageControl.Visible = ShowIt;
}
```

Sorry, missed part about Master Page...  As a web control, as long as control is visible from the IDE (visual designer) of your form, you can refer to it directly in the CONTROL's code-behind partial class definition by the explicit name reference...

```
public Boolean ImgVisible
{
   get { return ImgControl.Visible; }
   set { ImgControl.Visible = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a problem accessing this on the content page. Is this right?

1. I went to codebehind on control and added the following property:

   `public Boolean ImgVisible
   {
     get { return this.imgModule1Passed.Visible; }
     set { this. imgModule1Passed.Visible = value; }
   }`
2. on the content page code behind, I am using the following:

`UserControl control = (usercontrol)this.Page.Master.FindControl("QuizzesPassed1");`

Shouldn't I be able to find the property by:

Control.ImgVisible

?

I can't seem to find the control at all.

Comment: you should cast the Control into your specific subtype, since only it contains the ImgVisible property.